# Plot the F-distribution from an lm object in R

Tags: r, models

Suppose we have two variables that we wish to build a model from:

```
set.seed(10239)
x <- rnorm(seq(1,100,1))
y <- rnorm(seq(1,100,1))
model <- lm(x~y)

class(model)
# [1] "lm"

summary(model)
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = x ~ y)
# 
# Residuals:
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -3.08676 -0.63022 -0.01115  0.75280  2.35169 
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) -0.07188    0.11375  -0.632    0.529
# y            0.06999    0.12076   0.580    0.564
# 
# Residual standard error: 1.117 on 98 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.003416,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.006754 
# F-statistic: 0.3359 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.5635
```

How do you plot the F-distribution of the `model` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the structure of the summary of your model `str(summary(model))`, you'll notice that the parameters for the F-distribution of interest can be found by calling `summary(model)$fstatistic`. The first element in the list is the F-statistic and the following two element are the numerator degrees of freedom and the denominator degrees of freedom, in that order. So to plot the F-distribution, try something like the following

```
df <- summary(model)$fstatistic
curve(df(x, df1 = df[2], df2 = df[3]), from = 0, to = 100)
```

Alternatively, you can also get the parameters for the F-distribution of interest from the model itself. The numerator degrees of freedom is one less than the number of coefficients in the model and the denominator degrees of freedom is the total number of observations less one more than the number of coefficients in the model.

```
df1 <- length(model$coefficients) - 1
df2 <- length(model$residuals) - df1 - 1
curve(df(x, df1 = df1, df2 = df2), from = 0, to = 100)
```

Comment: A couple of comments: i) `df2` can be computed using `df.residual(model)`, ii) in general use, be wary of grabbing things like residuals from a model instead of using the extractor function. Where a model has more than one type of residual, `$residuals` might contain working residuals (e.g. `glm()`) which will rarely be what you want, whereas `resid(model)` would return something different and something more useful than working residuals. +1 for showing `curve()`.

Comment: It is confusing that you call the F statistic variables `df`, since this is also the name of a function you use. Would be clear use an alternative name, such as `fs`. Its also worth noting that the first argument to the `curve` function is an expression, so the `x` within `df` there is not the same `x` as in the model. Still its a good use of curve, +1.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the following way to show the p-value of the F distribution

```
fstat <- summary(model)$fstatistic

library(HH)
old.omd <- par(omd=c(.05,.88, .05,1))
F.setup(df1=fstat['numdf'], df2=fstat['dendf'])
F.curve(df1=fstat['numdf'], df2=fstat['dendf'], col='blue')
F.observed(fstat['value'], df1=fstat['numdf'], df2=fstat['dendf'])
par(old.omd)
```

[image]